# How to disable keyboard on specific textField but allow picker view as input Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have 2 textFields in a view controller one uses a pickerView as input and the other uses a keyboard, the problem is the keyboard is still enabled under the pickerView. I have it set up that when the textfield in the bottom is being used the keyboard moves the view up to make the textField visible but when i click on the top textField which uses the pickerView it also moves the view up and you can't see the input on that textField. I need to only use the pickerView on top textField so the view won't move up when that textfield is being used. 
Here is what i'm using to move view up:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    bottomConstraint.constant = 200
    topConstraint.constant = -200
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}



func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    bottomConstraint.constant = 8
    topConstraint.constant = 10
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Here is my setup for the pickerView in viewDidLoad: (colorCodePicker is the textField with pickerView as input)

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    pickerView.delegate = self

    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    colorCodePicker.inputView = pickerView
```

I have tried most of the solutions here but haven't got any to work i.e. if i disable user input than i can't call the pickerView, also tried inserting a clear button over the textField like one of the suggestions with no luck. Or maybe a solution to only move view up when bottom textField is active, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` check `if colorCodePicker.isFirstResponder()` to decide whether to change the constraint.

Comment: @ zcui93 exactly what i needed thanks it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I know it won't be exact answer but if you just use IQKeyboardManager you do not need to think about those staff in any scene of your application.

[IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/)

Answer (score 1):

There can be quick fixes to save the day but I'd suggest using `UITableViewController` for building form pages. It automatically does keyboard handling. Yes, you need to create `UITableViewCell`s which contain `UITextField`s but I think this is feasible.

I do not like using stand-alone `UITableViewController` since they do not have a `UIView` as their `self.view`, therefore I embed them to my view controller and access its `tableView` during segue. Even if it is not `dataSource`/`delegate` of its `tableView`, it handles keyboard.